# MD5 reduce AES reliability?

Tags: encryption, md5

I'll planed use AES128 with md5 for short messaging (16-64 bytes) with server. I know about MD5 use, it's bad idea, but I think MD5 the best hash solution for iot embedded processors. My messages will be pretty short. Hash will contain decrypted data + some constant "fingerprint" from firmware. I have question about using CBC mode + MD5. When I encrypt first 16 bytes message I got some results from AES and MD5, and then next 16bytes with same input data give me different AES and same MD5. How that fact reduce encryption reliability for AES? Or need use ECB mode?

Comment: There are lightweight ciphers like SIMON, PRESENT that use 64-block size that you might interest.

Answer (score 1):

AES is not a cipher, it is a *block cipher*. Often it is used in CBC mode where each generated ciphertext block is XOR'ed with the next plaintext block before it is encrypted. AES blocks *should always* be different from previous ciphertext blocks as it would otherwise leak information on the input to an adversary: you can tell that the input blocks are identical if the ciphertext blocks are identical.

So you are wrong that it might reduce encryption reliability: it increases security instead. And no, you should *never ever* use ECB mode without proving that it is secure in your protocol (and that's probably not something you should do yourself). Using MD5 here is not *just* wrong. You should at least use HMAC-MD5 instead to achieve integrity and message authenticity, preferably over the ciphertext rather than the plaintext.

Comment: And studying cryptography and reviewing your design before starting to type in code would help too.